# Do you capitalize this sentence after colon?

Tags: grammar, capitalization, colons

I'm using a style of capitalizing a complete sentence after a colon.

Here's the example sentence:

> To minimize the time needed to traverse the large forest, I divided the fifty guards into three groups: twenty stood guard on the mountain, fifteen would lead the unwilling villagers back to the city, while the rest would accompany me back to the makeshift settlement near the mansion.

I don't know if this count as complete sentence, since if it has a construction like this instead:

> To minimize the time needed to traverse the large forest, I divided the fifty guards into three groups equally: to stand guard on the mountain, to lead the unwilling villagers back to the city, and to accompany me back to the makeshift settlement near the mansion.

It won't be capitalized.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apart from the pedantic observation that 50 does not divide exactly by 3 in the second example, could you please give an example of where you think something should be capitalised after a colon? The question is not clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

You would not use a capital letter.  Although the part before the colon is a complete sentence, the parts after it are not sentences. In particular the phrase "while the rest..." is not a sentence, as it starts with a subordinating conjunction.

If you are making sentences you should use full stops at the end, as you would with a bullet list:

> ...into three groups:
>
> - Twenty stood guard on the mountain.
> - Fifteen would lead the unwilling villagers back to the city.
> - The rest would accompany me back to the makeshift settlement near the mansion.